# I am trying to plot a pair of list from flask on a multi axis bar chart using Chart.js. I am able to plot the chart but cannot display the legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have been trying to plot a pair of lists returned using json on an html page using chart.js. I have been able to plot the data using chart.js but haven't been able to create the legend. The code for the chart.js function is given below -

```js
function addData(chartID, labels, data) {
      Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;
      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
      Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = true;

      var ctx = document.getElementById(chartID).getContext('2d');
      var newChartData = {};

      newChartData.type = "bar";
      newChartData.data = {};
      newChartData.data.labels = [];
      newChartData.data.datasets = [];
      newChartData.options = {};
      newChartData.options.legend = {
        enabled: true,
        display: true,
      };
      newChartData.options.legend.labels = {
        fontColor: 'black',
        fontSize: 18
      }

      data.labels.forEach((label) => {
        newChartData.data.labels.push(label);
      });
      data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        newChartData.data.datasets.push(dataset);
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(newChartData, null, 2));
      console.log(newChartData);

      var chart_plot = new Chart(ctx, newChartData);
      chart_plot.update();
    }




    var lab = ['TV', 'Press', 'Airport OOH', 'Search', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Display', 'Affiliates'];

    var dataFirst = {
      label: "% Change in Spends",
      data: [20, 15, 60, 60, 65, 30, 70],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)',
        'rgba(219, 0, 17, 0.8)'
      ],
      // Set More Options
    };

    var dataSecond = {
      label: "% Change in Applications",
      data: [0, 59, 75, 20, 20, 55, 40],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)',
        'rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.8)'
      ],
      // Set More Options
    };

    var speedData = {
      labels: ['TV', 'Press', 'Airport OOH', 'Search', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Display', 'Affiliates'],
      datasets: [dataFirst, dataSecond]
    };

addData('chart_plot', lab, speedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="chart_plot" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Things I have tried to do -

1. Tried "Chart.defaults.global.legend = true;"
2. Tried "newChartData.options.legend = {enabled:true, display:true,};
   newChartData.options.legend.labels = {fontColor: 'black', fontSize: 18}"

I am new to JS, Jquery & chart.js. I am sure I am missing some crucial piece of code here. I would be grateful if someone would just tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Welcome RajdeepB, I see the legends in your example at the top https://jsfiddle.net/b6q1detu/ Which browser are you using?

Comment: @gengns I am using Google Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (32-bit)). I have encapsulated the canvas tag inside a div tag. Could the div tag cause issues?

Comment: Could you update to the latest version an check if you see legends in my example linked above? https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/chrome

Comment: @gengns I cannot update the browser since it's controlled by the organization. However, I see that codepen and fiddle both show the legend. I believe the div which is on the outside of the canvas tag is causing issues since changing the position keyword to 'left', right', 'top' or 'bottom' screws up the chart itself.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, you are in the right direction, as you said it seems like that `div` is the main culprit. Hope your company let you keep updated your browser, it's so painful when you have to deal with security issues, performance or want to use new standard tecnologies.

Comment: @gengns thank you for your feedback and help... Appreciate it :)